# How to use the rails match method with a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Is there a way to use the rails `match` method with a simple string, rather than a regular expression?
I'm trying to match a url as such

```
sometext.match('http://www.example.com')
```

The problem is, this is stil getting evaluated as a regular expression, so I have to escape all the special characters for this to work properly, as such:

```
sometext.match('http:\/\/www.example\.com\?foo=bar')
```

If there's no way to match just a string, is there a way to escape it automatically for regular expressions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want to know if a string is part of another, use `include?`.

```
sometext.include?("http://www.example.com/")
```

Comment: You can also use `start_with?` and `end_with?` if you want to anchor the string to the beginning or the end. However, I refuse to use them because they are grammatically incorrect most of the time, and that bugs me. Fortunately, ActiveSupport has `starts_with?` and `ends_with?` so in Rails you're covered. Outside of Rails, you can still use it manually with `require 'active_support/core_ext/string/starts_ends_with'`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like:

```
sometext =~ %r{http://example.com?foo=bar}
```